# How to properly divide equations and inequalities by a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's consider a simple equation:

$$3x^2-2x+x=x^2-1$$

or inequality

$$3x^2-2x+x < x^2-1$$

or

$$3x^2-2x+x > x^2-1$$

How to properly divide by $x^2-1$. In many examples I've seen it is stated that division can be done properly only if $x^2-1$ is squared so it is always greater than zero, but no deeper explanation is given. Could somebody give wide explanation of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can't divide by zero, so you need $x^2 \neq 1$. If your divide the inequalities, you need to take account of the sign of $x^2-1$ (if negative, it 'flips' the inequality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the expression by which you are dividing is smaller than zero, then the inequality reverses.

Example : $-3<2$, dividing both sides by $-1$, we have the inequality reversed or $3>-2$.

Therefore you should check cases for if $x^2-1<0$ then after dividing reverse the inequality  or if it is greater than zero then inequality does not get reversed.

Comment: So I should consider two (or three) parts of the domain? One for $x^2-1>0$ and two for $x^2-1<0$ ?

Comment: yes. $1)$ $x^2-1<0$ and $2)$ $x^2-1>0$ and $3)$ $x^2-1 \neq 0$.

Comment: And what with equality?

Comment: There is no need to consider cases in equality simply take the terms in R.H.S to L.H.S, simplify, and apply splitting middle term or quadratic formula

Answer (score 2):

There in no need to deal with cases.  Assume, $f$ and $g$ are continous function, defined on some interval.  To solve $f(x)<g(x)$, solve $f(x)-g(x)=0$.  Between consecutive zeros  the sign of $f-g$ is constant.

Michael